# Unable to install Ubuntu derivatives.

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I tried to install two Ubuntu derivatives with Win7 (Zorin core 64 bit, Lubuntu 18.04) and every time I do, an error message pops up stating "grub install dev/sda failed. This is a fatal error." and the installer crashes. I have tried to use Unetbootin, Etcher and UUI only to get the same error. I am attempting to dual boot with Win7. Every time the installer crashes my laptop boots into windows and the partitions are made. I guess it is something on my laptop that is preventing the installer. How do I fix it?

Comment: What *specific* laptop is this? Have you looked on the product support forums for the *specific* laptop make and model?

Comment: It's an old HP Notebook 1000. I think it is bios but not quite sure. How do you check that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Read it on another website and if it gives the same error then when you are about to decide the partitions it will ask you whether to force uefi or bios. Click on "Go Back" and carry on with the rest of the installation as usual. This time it should pass by without the error. And in some cases, it results in missing windows on boot menu. Reboot the machine and select "Advanced options for (your linux)" then without wandering around, make some obvious choices and you would be presented with a strange pink background and some options. Choose to "Update grub" or simply "Grub". Let it do some command line-y stuff and finally, yaay! Windows is back! And Linux is there as well. To make any additional changes to the boot menu, try grub customizer. Get instructions and file here:
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/04/install-grub-customizer-ubuntu-16-04-lts/
Thanks to all others.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be uefi problem. Try booting in bios or legacy mode and then install the distro you want and this time grub would install.

If you want uefi installation, check [this.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)